# Remove the old installed version of an application when installing a new version from source?

Tags: software-installation

I am installing a newer version of Wine by compiling from source, and then will use checkinstall to create a deb package, and then install it from the deb file by dpkg.

At the same time I would like to remove the old version of wine to reclaim the space.

i worry about software dependency problem. How can I install the newer version and remove the older one  safely?

Answer (score 1):

**First, remove wine**

```
$> apt-get remove wine
```

[**Second, install Wine dependency packages**](http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install-wine-deps.sh)

(This script contains a manifest of wine dependencies.)

**Third, build wine from source**

```
$> ./configure
$> make depend
$> make
$> make install
```

[**Fourth, install WineTricks**](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks)

(This package contains enhanced tricks for Windows emulation.)