# Possible to know how much space and time the installation of some application from source takes?

Tags: software-installation

I am installing wine 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 by compiling the source, since [I can't find a binary from a ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531516/cant-find-wine1-6-2-after-adding-a-ppa).

But as I am now compiling the source in `/tmp`, the free space of my `/` has dropped to 70Mb. It has been quite  a while, and I don't know how long it will take to finish compiling, or where I am in the progress towards finishing compiling. Now I have stopped the compiling. I am stopped at

```
gcc -c -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include  -DWINE_STRICT_PROTOTYPES -DWINE_NO_NAMELESS_EXTENSION -DWIDL_C_INLINE_WRAPPERS  -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wempty-body -Wignored-qualifiers -Wstrict-prototypes -Wtype-limits -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0  -o automation.o automation.c
gcc -c -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include  -DWINE_STRICT_PROTOTYPES -DWINE_NO_NAMELESS_EXTENSION -DWIDL_C_INLINE_WRAPPERS  -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wempty-body -Wignored-qualifiers -Wstrict-prototypes -Wtype-limits -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0  -o db.o db.c
gcc -c -I. -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include  -DWINE_STRICT_PROTOTYPES -DWINE_NO_NAMELESS_EXTENSION -DWIDL_C_INLINE_WRAPPERS  -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wempty-body -Wignored-qualifiers -Wstrict-prototypes -Wtype-limits -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0  -o format.o format.c
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 make
```

Is it possible to know how long and much space an installation from compiling source might take?

What would you do better, if you were me? Thanks.

Comment: Compiling from source can take a while, depending on the processing capacity of your system. WINE compiled from source shouldn't take up more than 250MB. I'm unsure why you are compiling in /tmp/. If I were you, I would build in /usr/opt/.

Comment: (1) my compiled wine takes more than 250MB already, and the size is still increasing. so I decide to ctrl-z it. (2) I do it in /tmp, because I think the files are not worth keeping after I finish installation, and I don't have unlimited space for keeping them. Am I right?

Comment: If you tell me what kind of CPU you have, I might be able to give you a general idea of how long a build of WINE would take.

Comment: what about (2)? My CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8800  @ 2.66GHz`, but I limit the working frequency to be 800MHz, because of overheating.

Comment: How about giving a try to the `.deb`s from Debian? Jessie and Sid have 1.6.2 already.

Comment: @Alex: where can I download it?

Comment: [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wine), I would extract them with `dpkg -x <deb> directory/` then use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` to get it running, you'll need at least `wine` and `libwine` may be some other, if you download `wine` from `Jessie` use the same for the others (don't mix)

Comment: See my Answer for where/how to download and install an officially supported package.  The reason you're suffering an install failure is because packages need to be removed/updated.  Follow my answer then post the output you get.  Please note that Wine 1.6.2 is not available in the repo.  1.6.1 is the last stable version.  If you  need >=1.6.2 try `wine1.7`

Answer (score 2):

**Measure GCC Compile Time**

```
$> time ./configure
$> time make depend
$> time make
$> time make install
```

The *time* utility provides statistics on compile time for your system. After you build with the time measurement utility, you can check the size of your directory with:

**Measure Build Size**

```
$> DIRECTORY="/source/compiler/output/directory"    
$> du -m $DIRECTORY
```

**Does it really even matter where you build?**

No, this is just another *holy war* that developers engage in... It's just a $PATH. Compile it in /tmp/, /opt/, /home/, /root/, anywhere: it's a matter of preference.

I do things in /opt/src/ because I keep the source code, because I modify it for my particular requirement.

**Estimate**

I estimate your compile time should not run beyond 2 hours.

Estimating compile time is an analytical process of researching how long it takes other people to compile the source who have similar processors (i.e., Intel), and doing some rough math which is hardly scientific.

[User Reporting Compile time for Wine on Faster Processor](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1533514)

How I derived the answer:

A) Quad-Core Intel Processor with 4 Threads.
vs.
B) Dual-Core Processor with 2 Threads.

While user A is able to compile with 4 processes of GCC, you only can use 2.

Simply multiplying their time (15 minutes) times 2 to account for the thread reduction... Then multiplying by 2 again to compensate for the many variables involved (i.e., compiler version), I come up with 2 hours.

[Phoronix GCC Benchmarks](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=gcc_49_pentium&num=1)

The blog captioned above always contains updates on the state of GCC benchmarks. You can also adjust for your version of GCC by understanding how the compile times are relative between versions.

**Estimating Package Size**

Add the size of the compiled binary with the size of the compiled dependencies. WINE will actually compile without dependencies.

[Script that Installs WINE Dependencies and contains full wine DEP list](http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install-wine-deps.sh)

[Example of WINE and WINE-Dev packages in Distribution Repository](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wine/)

[Other Answer I have made about Building WINE from Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158915/remove-the-old-installed-version-of-an-application-when-installing-a-new-version/158919#158919)

I know that it may seem like I'm telling you to count all the beans, but in my world, there are only beans and bags of beans which I exchange beans between (most professionally).

Comment: I asked how to know how long and much space an installation might take before actual installation, not really timing and "spacing" an ongoing installation.

Comment: " modify it for my particular requirement", what particular requirement? Do you mean you can study how to implement wine?

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/ is an example of a repository I pull from regularly. This is the entire Source Code to Linux, and I can change anything in it before I compile it. I can do the same with WINE or any other Open-Source software that provides the code in a GPL-License compliant form that I am able to build from Source. So if WINE isn't working for a certain application, perhaps I can modify it to work for the application I require to run under its umbrella.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible scenario in your case is to compare compilation time of the same package with other, similar hardware.

We know nothing about your hardware, but just to give you rough idea -- I have a netbook at hand (intel atom CPU, old and weak machine) with gentoo, so I can easily calculate compilation time for all `wine` packages in last 3 years:

```
$ qlop -tHgv wine
wine-1.2.3: Sat Sep 17 22:41:18 2011: 1 hour, 29 minutes, 25 seconds
wine-1.2.2: Mon Sep 19 05:42:32 2011: 1 hour, 14 minutes, 0 seconds
wine-1.2.2: Sun Oct  9 06:27:57 2011: 1 hour, 9 minutes, 3 seconds
wine-1.2.2: Sun Jan 22 13:31:16 2012: 1 hour, 19 minutes, 7 seconds
wine-1.4: Fri Jul  6 14:29:27 2012: 1 hour, 45 minutes, 48 seconds
wine-1.4.1: Thu Jul 19 23:38:10 2012: 1 hour, 24 minutes, 57 seconds
wine-1.4.1: Thu Dec 27 15:14:27 2012: 2 hours, 2 minutes, 2 seconds
wine-1.4.1: Sat Jan 26 02:27:28 2013: 3 hours, 8 minutes, 35 seconds
wine-1.4.1: Sun Feb 17 00:45:56 2013: 1 hour, 20 minutes, 12 seconds
wine-1.6: Mon Sep 23 18:15:04 2013: 2 hours, 28 minutes, 58 seconds
wine-1.6: Sat Jan 11 21:30:48 2014: 1 hour, 48 minutes, 36 seconds
wine-1.6.1: Mon Jan 27 22:47:25 2014: 2 hours, 48 minutes, 27 seconds
wine-1.6.2: Sat Mar 15 06:30:29 2014: 1 hour, 52 minutes, 17 seconds
wine-1.6.2: Sun Jul 13 18:05:58 2014: 2 hours, 2 minutes, 30 seconds
wine: 14 times
```

and size:

```
$ qsize -mf wine
app-emulation/wine-1.6.2: 2,630 files, 49 non-files, 207 MiB
```

Comment: It seems `qlop` isn't avaliable in Ubuntu's apt-cache search

Comment: Well, `qlop` is a gentoo tool and even if it would be available in ubuntu it wouldn't work there, because ubuntu uses binary packages, doesn't it?

Comment: @jimmij Don't feel sorry for the non Gentoo users here.  We must show them the power of the dark side.  On a more serious note, understanding the difference between a binary distro and a source distro has helped me in helping others here.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't Use a Source Package on a Binary Distribution !!!**

This will lead to unforeseen issues such as:

- The compiled programs expect the Binaries it uses to be in one place and Ubuntu installs them somewhere differently.
- Missing Symlinks to Libraries.
- Mismatched versions.
- etc.

Instead use the [official Wine PPA](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

1. Open the Software Sources menu by launching the Ubuntu Software Center and selecting Edit->Software Sources. Choose the Other Software tab and click Add.
2. Type ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa.  Click Add.
3. `apt-get update && apt-get install wine1.6`

This should fetch and install the version you're going to fail miserably at compiling because of the reasons I mentioned above.  The time it takes is a moot point.

Comment: Is there a ppa for wine 1.7?

Comment: It's the same PPA Use the steps above and replace `wine1.6` in Step 3, with `wine1.7`.  You can also click the PPA Link above and follow the directions there as they are the same as these with more fluff.

Comment: Will i be able to install wine 1.6.2 by your way?

Comment: @Tim No, Wine 1.6.1 is the last one in the [Wine PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) is 1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1.   See my comment above regarding 1.7.